# Как изменить цвет подсветки таких же переменных в PhpStorm ?

Tags: phpstorm, php

**Добрый день!**

Специально пересмотрел все заданные вопросы про PhpStorm (на сей момент их было 39) и не нашел ответа на свой вопрос.

Имеется PhpStorm 6-ой версии с Default визуальной цветовой схемой.

Создаю PHP файл и естественно, пишу PHP код.
Предположим, выделяю переменную $a, PhpStorm подсвечивает другие переменные $a, однако очень тускло. 
Вопрос в следующем: **как можно изменить цвет подсветки других таких же переменных ?**
(чтобы было ярко и четко подсвечивались)
Копаюсь в Settings -> Editor -> Colors&Fonts -> PHP (все перебрал из списка, однако подсветку таких же переменных не смог пока найти...

**Подскажите пожалуйста** что-нибудь по данному поводу.

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: В восьмом / ЕАР (еще раз подчеркну, что не в шестом) это, похоже, лежит по следующему адресу:

IDE Settings - Editor - Colors & Fonts - General - Search result (write access)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IDE Settings - Editor - Colors & Fonts - General - Identifier under caret

Comment: Спасибо, теперь сделал четкий цвет )